# Changing Color in nPlot for discreteBarChart

Tags: r, rcharts

I'm trying to change the color of the bars for a discreteBarChart using nPlot, but the color argument doesn't seem to change anything in the example below:

```
data(cars) 
speedTableVec<-table(cars$speed) 
speedTable<-data.frame(speedTableVec)
n1<-nPlot(Freq ~ Var1, data=speedTable, type="discreteBarChart", color="blue")
n1
```

Is there a way to keep the bars consistently one color (i.e. blue)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. I presume you were looking to use `NVD3` and `nPlot`. See [here](http://rcharts.io/viewer/?6886158) for the final chart.

```
data(cars) 
speedTableVec<-table(cars$speed) 
speedTable<-data.frame(speedTableVec)
require(rCharts)
n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Var1, data = speedTable, type="discreteBarChart")
n1$chart(color = "#! function(d){ return 'blue'} !#")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're presumption was correct that I'm looking to use nPlot. This is exactly what I was looking to do. Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up. I'm trying to add an axis label, but `n1$chart(xAxis=list(axisLabel='Var1'))` doesn't seem to do the trick. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How do I pass on an array of colors, e.g. for plotting multiple lines in a lineChart with different colors?